# Android Listview Row Layout

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm developing what I thought would be a simple listview row layout, but I'm having some trouble getting my views to line up properly.  There are 4 TextViews all using layout_weight within a LinearLayout to size themselves appropriately.  What I can't figure out, however, is how to align them consistently so that each TextView begins in the same position as the one above and beneath it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#AAAAAA88">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5px"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"       
        android:padding="5px"           
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_grade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"       
        android:padding="5px"           
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"       
        android:padding="2px"           
    />        

</LinearLayout>
```

My attempts to use the :gravity tag don't seem to work.  Is LinearLayout the wrong approach here?

As an edit, I'm making some headway using specific width values in dips.  Now to test if it looks the same across different screens.

Answer (score 0):

The gravity distributes the remainder of space available after minimum constraints not the total space.

So align different row above and below make sure the remaining space is equal on each row. A good way to accomplish this is to hard-code the minimum space each element needs:

```
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_width="1dip"
```

Make each TextView on every row 1dip width and split the remaining space according to weight.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `RelativeLayout`. Try 4 of the TextViews to be placed relatively, 3 can have fixed width in dp and the 4th can take up  rest of the available space. that way each textview will start at a fixed position every time.

something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Text 1"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Text 2"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_3"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_2"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Text 3"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Text 4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```